# Is there a Jack equivalent for nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jack, narwhal

Is there an equivalent to Jack for Narhwal implemented in nodejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of, but not really.  There's Kris Zyp's jsgi-node (installable as `npm install jsgi`) at https://github.com/kriszyp/jsgi-node.

The most popular middleware-stacking thing in NodeJS is Connect.  Rather than using connect directly, most people use [Express](http://expressjs.com/).

Comment: Also, check out common-node, which uses fibers to emulate the sync APIs in commonjs. http://olegp.github.com/common-node/

Answer (score 0):

You can  try this great framework :[vert.x](http://vertx.io)